# cordova.js file not found in ionic app?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

While I am running app in android device i am getting this error and also inappbrowser is not working help me out ...

Error

```
   file:///android_asset/www/js/cordova.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
    app.js:8 Route change!!! 
    app.js:8 Route change!!! /home
    file:///android_asset/www/%7B%7Bn.imgurl%7D%7D Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
    file:///android_asset/www/%7B%7Bt.imgurl%7D%7D Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
    ionic.bundle.min.js:22 'Touch.webkitRadiusX' is deprecated and will be removed in M47, around November 2015. Please use 'Touch.radiusX' instead.
    ionic.bundle.min.js:22 'Touch.webkitRadiusY' is deprecated and will be removed in M47, around November 2015. Please use 'Touch.radiusY' instead.
    ionic.bundle.min.js:22 'Touch.webkitRotationAngle' is deprecated and will be removed in M47, around November 2015. Please use 'Touch.rotationAngle' instead.
    ionic.bundle.min.js:22 'Touch.webkitForce' is deprecated and will be removed in M47, around November 2015. Please use 'Touch.force' instead.


index.html 
<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- your app's css -->
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/tabSlideBox.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- ionic/angularjs scripts -->
    <!--<script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-rc.4/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script> -->
    <!--<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>   -->
  <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>   
  <script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/cordova.js"></script> 
  <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
   <script src="js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="js/tabSlideBox.js"></script>
```

Comment: try re-adding platform. It will give you `cordova.js` file and you can add reference to that. As it will get cordova, plugins will start working again.

Comment: I am Working on it , let u know if it works , Thanks Hardik

Comment: Did not work Hardik

Comment: what problem you are facing ? can you give detail on error ?

Comment: Are you referencing `cordova.js` file in `index.html` ?

Comment: Note : cordova file is in root of platform's www folder, not in js folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
<script src="js/cordova.js"></script>
```

to

```
 <script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Comment: want to notify here. in my case it was already 'cordova.js' but error still occured.

Answer (score 3):

When you run **cordova platform add android** and then **cordova build android**, you should get a **cordova.js added project/platforms/android/assets/www folders**. You don't need to add it in your js  files. so, just declare it in index.js file as follows,

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```